# How to verify interrupt handler on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, interrupt

Am understanding interrupts usage in linux. I have below sample linux driver code in linux which requests for an IRQ and registers an interrupt handler.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/of_gpio.h>

static int irq = 50; // Initialize to an invalid GPIO number

static irqreturn_t peripheral_interrupt_handler(int irq, void *data)
{
    pr_info("Am in interrupt Handler\n");
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int __init peripheral_interrupt_init(void)
{
    int ret;

    pr_info("Requesting for IRQ %d\n",irq);

    ret = request_irq(irq, peripheral_interrupt_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING,
                      "peripheral_interrupt", NULL);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("Failed to request IRQ %d\n", irq);
        return ret;
    }

    pr_info("Peripheral interrupt handler registered for IRQ %d\n",irq);
    return 0;
}


static void __exit peripheral_interrupt_exit(void)
{
    free_irq(irq, NULL);
    pr_info("Peripheral interrupt handler removed\n");
}

module_init(peripheral_interrupt_init);
module_exit(peripheral_interrupt_exit);
```

How can i validate this code by using an HW interrupt like a key press on KB etc.
Appreciate any help by the dev community.

Comment: tried few things. registering IRQ6 (floppy drive interrupt) is successful but unable to trigger this interrupt as my SUT does'nt have FD.
Any such free IRQs are possible for registering and triggering.?

Comment: You need to explain what hardware you are running on, how you selected irq 50, and how you are preventing the system from already claiming the hardware and assigning its own interrupt handler. `cat /proc/interrupts` will list the known registered interrupts.

Comment: @stark, to begin with the fact that `request_irq()` expects **Linux** interrupt and **NOT** a hardware one. And obviously chained handler won't be called if the previous one handled the IRQ (IIRC how it works).

Comment: You can't. You need to know what kind of the interrupt in **Linux** number space is being used and if and only if it's has shared flag set, you may chain another IRQ action (a.k.a. handler) to do something about it. Since modern keyboards are USB, it will be interesting task to you to understand how it works.

Comment: @stark, am using **ubuntu OS on X86 platform**. 
Few blogs mentioned **CTRL + F9** generates IRQ50 hence used this.
But not seeing 50 under /proc/interrupts

Am trying to capture an user generated interrupt with interrupt handler which is shared above.

Comment: @0andriy, Am not exclusively looking to trigger an interrupt from KB and capture the event in the driver.
IRQ6 (Floppy Drive) is seen in /proc/interrupts/ and request_irq() is also success for this. is there a way to trigger this IRQ6.?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if you trigger it, how will you know that the floppy handler doesn't handle it and IRQ core won't try handle it second time? Here is how shared IRQ is set: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/irq/manage.c#L1613 (pay attention to the L1652), here is how it's handled:  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/irq/handle.c#L147. Homework: to answer the above questions yourself.

Comment: As for IRQ 50 you are completely misunderstanding what's that. It solely depends on the platform. Do you have schematics of your hardware, do you know what Ctrl+F9 means? Why the heck it should generate that IRQ and what the meaning of the number?